# Is there a network discovery and mapper program for OSX?

Tags: macos

I am looking for a software that can create a network topology diagram that runs on OSX. Please give me your suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Infoblox has a VM tool for network discovery and reporting (don't think it will do diagrams though): http://www.infoblox.com/downloads/software/ip-address-management-freeware

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what do you want exactly, but you can try the [lansurveyor](http://mac.brothersoft.com/lansurveyor.html).

Discovers and draws topological maps for TCP/IP and AppleTalk networks. 
Features network node Up/down testing (polling) for both TCP/IP and AppleTalk nodes with alerts, including paging and email.

- Automatically discovers and diagrams network topology
- Supports generation of network maps in Microsoft Office® Visio®
- Automatically detects new devices and changes to network topology
- Simplifies inventory management for hardware and software assets
- Addresses reporting needs for PCI compliance and other regulatory requirements

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try "Zenmap" (an nmap GUI implementation), the download link is:
http://nmap.org/download.html
The OSX link is somewhere at the bottom of the page.

It’s maybe not the perfect »topology mapper« (though it has a nice clickable graphic mode) but offers a lot of insight due to using nmap »under the hood«.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked but not sure how to use the Topology feature. Seems like my localhost is in the center of everything instead of my 192.168.1.1 router. Advice?

Comment: Is it at all possible that your network setup is »bad«? (I.e., your machine is not in the same network, has a bad subnet mask, or the like?) Can you »ping« any of the other devices?

If your network setup is correct, it might still be some settings on the other devices to be scanned: Restrictive firewalling, or ICMP echo requests are disabled.

Still odd. I’ve seldom run across a network that nmap (or Zenmap, in this case) couldn’t somehow »see«. Anyone?

Comment: Re: Topology: Unfortunately, I’m on my laptop now and can’t boot into Linux rightaway, but … I *think* I remember that clicking on any one device will bring it into the center. and re-arrange the topology map. Also, play with the settings (zoom, etc.) on the right.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://nmap.org/book/zenmap-topology.html) helps for moving around in the topology map … Good luck!

Comment: Yes I can move the router to the middle. My question is about the lines that shows connection between devices, and all devices are pictured as connected directly to my local host and not through the router as I would expect. I thought the trace route function is supposed to figure that out? I probably just don't understand fully how to use this yet. I did read the manual but haven't found anything about this. Thanks

Comment: Tried all the profiles on small and big networks. Same thing. All devices are connected only to localhost. I don't understand...

Comment: Maybe Zabbix is worth a look http://www.zabbix.com/screenshots.php at least the screenshots looks like it is useable

Answer (score -1):

[Joshaven Potter ported Microtik's "The Dude"](http://joshaven.com/resources/tools/the-dude-for-mac/) which is a well-regarded network walker and mapper for Windows as it boasts a lot of features. There are also client agents that can run on systems to provide data not presented presumably to SNMP or what NMAP can see. I am about to give it a try myself. I am trying to see if I am seeing switching bottlencks in my 6-deep stack of random switches to see if I need to make some VLANs so I am hoping it works. I will report back with my results in case you're interested.